# httpsでAWSのClassic load balancerのDNSに直接アクセスすることはできますか？

Tags: aws, amazon-elb

https://hogehoge-***.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
にアクセスすると

```
HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

と返ってくるのですが、これはELBが返しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 作成したELBは、クラッシクロードバランサでしょうか、ALBでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

作成したELBは、クラッシクロードバランサでしょうか、ALBでしょうか。

ELBが504を返している場合の調べ方と対処方法が下記のドキュメントにあります。
クラッシクロードバランサは使ったことがないので、わかりませんが、ALBはモニタタブでエラーの発生状況が確認できます。発生しているようであれば、接続タイムアウトの時間を長くすると良いかもしれません。

クラッシクロードバランサ
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504

ALB
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-504-issues